# Different ways to get string

Tags: java, android

May I ask what's the different between

```
getResources().getString(R.string.my_string);
```

and

```
getString(R.string.my_string);
```

and also just

```
R.string.my_string;
```

I know that both return different value

for example:

```
textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.my_string));
textView.setText(getString(R.string.my_string));
textView.setText(R.string.my_string);
```

I have try this three ways

all works

but I wonder to know why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi The Android resource system keeps track of all non-code assets associated with an application. You can use this class to access your application's resources. You can generally acquire the Resources instance associated with your application with `getResources()`.

practically there is no difference in `getString(R.string.your_string)` and `getResources().getString(R.string.my_string);` but I will suggest you to always use `getResources().getString(R.string.my_string);` for calling the resources.

`R.string.my_string;` will return the id(int) of the my_string. So this work like this `getResources()` is parent class contain all the resources of application by `getString()` you are informing the processor that your resource type is string and by `R.string.my_string` you give the id of your string.
Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

No difference, you can read the internal files.

     `/**
     * Return a localized string from the application's package's
     * default string table.
     *
     * @param resId Resource id for the string
     */
    @NonNull
    public final String getString(@StringRes int resId) {
        return getResources().getString(resId);
    }`